General solution to this coupled system of differential equations
I am trying to solve a circuit for the voltages at specific nodes as a function of time. I've made some changes to the problem given in as a textbook problem.
I have the following system of differential equations:
Note: j is not an imaginary number, it was just a poor choice of a constants name.
$$a\frac{dv_{1}(t)}{dt} + b*v_{1}(t) + c\frac{v_{2}(t)}{dt} + e*v_{2}(t) = f(t)$$
$$h\frac{dv_{1}(t)}{dt} + j*v_{1}(t) + k\frac{v_{2}(t)}{dt} + l*v_{2}(t) = 0$$
I tried following this video to solve the problem since it did not have the same form as any of the previous problems but I keep making some mistake since solutions never resolves if I plug back in my formulas for either $v_{1}$ or $v_{2}$.
Below is my handwritten attempt at solving the problem. Any help as to where I went wrong or a better way to solve the problem would be very appreciated.
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
Page 5

Given the ordinary differential equations system:
$$
\begin{cases}
a\,x'(t)+b\,x(t)+c\,y'(t)+d\,y(t)=u(t)\\
e\,x'(t)+f\,x(t)+g\,y'(t)+h\,y(t)=v(t)\\
\end{cases}
$$
let's start by rewriting it this way:
$$
\begin{cases}
\left(a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+b\right)x(t)+\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)y(t)=u(t)\\
\left(e\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+f\right)x(t)+\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)y(t)=v(t)\\
\end{cases}.
$$
So, multiplying both sides of the equations by the same factor:
$$
\begin{cases}
+\left(a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+b\right)\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)x(t)+\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)y(t)=+\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)u(t)\\
-\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)\left(e\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+f\right)x(t)-\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)y(t)=-\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)v(t)\\
\end{cases}
$$
it's possible to eliminate $y(t)$ by adding the two equations member by member:
$$\small
\left[\left(a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+b\right)\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)-\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)\left(e\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+f\right)\right]x(t)=\left(g\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+h\right)u(t)-\left(c\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+d\right)v(t)
$$
which can be simplified to:
$$
\boxed{x''(t)+\alpha\,x'(t)+\beta\,x(t)=\gamma(t)}
$$
where:
$$\small
\alpha:=\frac{a\,h+b\,g-c\,f-d\,e}{a\,g-c\,e},
\qquad
\beta:=\frac{b\,h-d\,f}{a\,g-c\,e},
\qquad
\gamma(t):=\frac{g\,u'(t)+h\,u(t)-c\,v'(t)-d\,v(t)}{a\,g-c\,e}.
$$
Once $x(t)$ is known, just substitute it into one of the two initial equations to determine $y(t)$ integrating indefinitely, so that the two initial conditions equalize the number of constants.
